# IOS 15 coping images from Ionic app on long press

Tags: ios, image, ionic-framework, ionic5, ios15

I just started testing my Ionic 5 app in IOS 15.0.2 and when I long press on any image it's allowing me to drag the image to other apps and photos and directly save it. When I drag the image to any text editor app, it shows the base64 string of the image.
The same is not happing in IOS 14 and I need to stop this behavior of the app. How can I control this from my ionic app?

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS resolved the issue.

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now there are no event fired on long press images.

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```css
-webkit-user-drag: none;
```

or you can reference：https://www.denisbouquet.com/css-forbid-selection-user-select-dragging-ghost-image/